# CentOS server to be used to internally issues

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, configuration, nagios

I have a CentOS 6 server here in our IT dept. and I want to install Nagios on it for some more network and enterprise insight. It has a internal IP that matches the network scheme as well as a hostname "Nagios".

I installed httpd services to get apache and after I restarted the server and try to go look for the test landing page to make sure Apache is up, I get nothing I tried both hostname and IP.

I issued a hostname command and the output was:

```
[root@Nagios ~]# hostname
Nagios.Nagios
```

my `/etc/hosts`    is set up as shown below

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

And my `/etc/sysconfig/network` looks as shown:

```
NETWORKING=yes
NETWORKING_IPV6=no
HOSTNAME=Nagios
GATEWAY=172.16.22.249
```

So when I put my IP in it doesn't resolve. I have restarted the httpd services and still nothing. What could the issue be?

***UPDATE***

Per the suggestion I have changed my hosts file to map:

This is now my host file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.0.1 nagios.localhost.com
172.16.22.249  nagios.localhost.com
nagios.localhost.com 172.16.22.249
172.16.22.249        localhost nagios.localhost.com
::1 localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
```

Comment: What happens when you type `localhost` in the address bar?

Comment: It says that the webpage is not available. I also removed just re-installed CentOS 6 clean again and its still giving me this issue.

Comment: Is your `hosts` file mapped to your local private IP?

Comment: I actually do not know how to do that, I am assuming its not. I will have to google that and see what I can do.

Comment: I have updated my question with what I did for mapping but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

k, so in /etc/sysconfig/network, you want to change

> HOSTNAME=Nagios

to be

> HOSTNAME=Nagios.yr.domain.name
>   (reboot)

and then in /etc/hosts, you want to remove the line

> nagios.localhost.com 172.16.22.249

and change the line

> 172.16.22.249  nagios.localhost.com

to read

> 172.16.22.249  nagios nagios.ur.domain.name
>   (mind the space between hostname and fqdn)

lastly, you want to remove the line

> 127.0.0.1 nagios.localhost.com

... alternatively, you could append "nagios" to the first line so as to read:

> 127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost NAGIOS

EDIT: DNS is case insensative

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://172.16.22.249
or check resolve.conf, stop iptable, firewall & selinux. hope you must have done this after a fresh installation.